# ColdFusion: "Error Executing Database Query. FUNCTION globalgoods.fullname does not exist "

Tags: coldfusion

Helping a nonprofit site with their recently retired CF site.  Site has been moved to new host and will be accessed only for historical needs. The URL has changed from http://globalgoodspartners.org to http://globalgoodspartners-org.securec77.ezhostingserver.com/ and that could be at least part of the issue.

Getting "Error Executing Database Query. FUNCTION globalgoods.fullname does not exist " when accessing the admin.  The error is preventing the admin menu from displaying.

Original CF dev is not available, and I do not know CF. I suspect that globalgoods.fullname needs to be redefined to match the new URL, but that's just a guess.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a built in SQL function missing form the database form the brief info you provided. We will need you to post relevant code and the full/complete error.

Comment: BTW - lots of missing image links on the 'new' URL.

Comment: I agree with Scott: you've got a function missing from the DB. You can't expect to administer/maintain a web app via Stack Overflow questions, really. It should not be too hard to engage a CF consultant to sort all this out for you.

Comment: Thanks guys... I appreciate the sound advice.